# I try to save submitted form to SQlite database using SQLAlchemy and get 'NoForeignKeysError'

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a simple web app using Python and Flask. I need to save data from submited for to SQlite database. But I get NoForeignKeysError.

Here is my form:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, IntegerField, SelectField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from wtforms.validators import NumberRange

class createProductForm(FlaskForm):
    prodSku = StringField('SKU', validators=[DataRequired()])
    prodName = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    prodLength = IntegerField('Length', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999)])
    prodWidth = IntegerField('Width', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999)])
    prodThick = IntegerField('Thickness', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999)])
    prodWeight = IntegerField('Weight', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=999999)])
    purchasePrice = IntegerField('Purchase Price', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999999)])
    prodPrice = IntegerField('Price', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999999)])
    ozonCategory = SelectField('Category', choices=[('catFisrt', 'Категория №1'), ('catSecond', 'Категория №2'), ('catThird', 'Категория №3')], validators=[DataRequired()])
    expOzonFbo = IntegerField('FBO expenses', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999999)])
    expOzonFbs = IntegerField('FBS expenses', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999999)])
    expOzonRealFbs = IntegerField('realFBS expenses', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=9999999)])
    submit = SubmitField('Create product')
```

Here is my database:

```
from app import db
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class ozonCategory(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "ozonCategories"
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    catName = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True)
    rateFbo = db.Column(db.Integer)
    rateFbs = db.Column(db.Integer)
    rateRealFbs = db.Column(db.Integer)

    products = relationship("product", back_populates="category")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<OZON Category {}>'.format(self.catName)

class product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "products"
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    prodSku = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    prodName = db.Column(db.String(300), index=True)
    prodLength = db.Column(db.Integer)
    prodWidth = db.Column(db.Integer)
    prodThick = db.Column(db.Integer)
    prodWeight = db.Column(db.Integer)
    purchasePrice = db.Column(db.Integer)
    prodPrice = db.Column(db.Integer)
    ozonCategory = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('ozonCategory.id'))
    expOzonFbo = db.Column(db.Integer)
    expOzonFbs = db.Column(db.Integer)
    expOzonRealFbs = db.Column(db.Integer)

    category = relationship("ozonCategory", back_populates="products")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Product {}>'.format(self.prodName)
```

Here is the function that is supposed to write submitted data to the database:

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect
from app import app, db
from app.forms import createProductForm
from app.models import product

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'username': 'Paul'}
    return render_template('index.html', title='Panel', user=user)

@app.route('/create-product', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def createProduct():
    form = createProductForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        currentProduct = product()
        currentProduct.prodSku = form.prodSku.data
        currentProduct.prodName = form.prodName.data
        currentProduct.prodLength = form.prodLength.data
        currentProduct.prodWidth = form.prodWidth.data
        currentProduct.prodThick = form.prodThick.data
        currentProduct.prodWeight = form.prodWeight.data
        currentProduct.purchasePrice = form.purchasePrice.data
        currentProduct.prodPrice = form.prodPrice.data
        currentProduct.ozonCategory = form.ozonCategory.data
        currentProduct.expOzonFbo = form.expOzonFbo.data
        currentProduct.expOzonFbs = form.expOzonFbs.data
        currentProduct.expOzonRealFbs = form.expOzonRealFbs.data    
        db.session.add(currentProduct)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('New product created')
        return redirect({{ url_for('main.index') }})
    return render_template('create-product.html', title='Create new product', form=form)
```

When I run my app ant try to submit the form I get this error:

`NoForeignKeysError( sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship ozonCategory.products - there are no foreign keys linking these tables. Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.`

I used 'ForeignKey' and 'relationship' to link the tables of the database but something is still wrong. Please help me to fix it.

Comment: `db.ForeignKey('ozonCategory.id')` should probably be `db.ForeignKey('ozonCategories.id')`, can you check that

Comment: Thank you. It worked and now I get this error:
**
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: products
[SQL: INSERT INTO products ("prodSku", "prodName", "prodLength", "prodWidth", "prodThick", "prodWeight", "purchasePrice", "prodPrice", "ozonCategory", "expOzonFbo", "expOzonFbs", "expOzonRealFbs") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('testSKU1', 'Test Prod 1', 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 'catSecond', 3, 3, 3)]
**

But it seems that I have table 'products':
'
class product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "products"
'

Where am I wrong?

Comment: If you have done https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#create-the-tables then I would suggest checking your sqlite database path, if you are using a relative path, can you update the path to absolute and check the same after you create the table?

Comment: Thank you, the problem was I did not create the tables :)